# Analysis of calls to a call center using poisson distribution

Tags: statistics

I have a set of data from my workplace where we note how many support calls we receive. I have been playing around with it in my spare time just to see if I could predict anything interesting.

I have been trying to fit the amount of calls to the poisson distribution and I know the MLE of the $\lambda$ parameter is the mean of the count of calls. What I would like to know is the following.

1. What is the best confidence interval for the $\lambda$ parameter? I know of a normal approximation and a few others but couldn't find any good derivation or proof that the significance value really is $(1-\alpha)$.
2. What can I say about the likelihood of an observation? How do I evaluate the likelihood of getting 0 calls for example? I'm aware that with the MLE I can use the PMF of the poisson to get an estimate for the likelihood of the observation but could I make an interval of probabilities with a certain significance?

Comment: I can't give a proof, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval gives a formula that answers your question.

Comment: @Ian I know thats the result but I can't seem to locate a proof. Also, it doesnt answer the second part of the question.

Comment: One answer would be the nonparametric one: define $F_n$ to be the empirical CDF and $\epsilon_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left ( \frac{2}{\alpha} \right )}$, then a $1-\alpha$-significant confidence interval for $F(x)$ is $(L(x),U(x))$ where $L(x)=\max \{ F_n(x)-\epsilon_n,0 \}$ and $U(x)=\min \{ F_n(x)+\epsilon_n,1 \}$. When the problem is suitable to parametric estimation (like in your case), this interval can wind up being longer than it "should" be.

Comment: An example: suppose you have 250 samples, one of them has zero calls, and you want to make a confidence interval with $\alpha=2e^{-5} \approx 0.014$. Then $\epsilon_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{500} \log(e^5)}=0.1$, $F_n(0)=\frac{1}{250}=0.004$,$L(x)=0,U(x)=0.104$. (As you can see, this is rather long, given how many samples you have.)

Answer (score 0):

A standard 95% CI for $\lambda$ for a particular time period based on
counting $X$ events in that time period is $X \pm 1.96\sqrt{X}.$
This is sometimes called a Wald interval; it uses a normal
approximation, and so works best for fairly large $X$.

A slight improvement is the CI $X + 2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{X + 1}.$
Its coverage probability tends to be closer to 95%. This interval
is based on the test of $H_0: \lambda = \lambda_0$ against
$H_a: \lambda \ne \lambda_0$, using the test statistic
$Z = (X - \lambda_0)/\sqrt{\lambda_0},$ rejecting $H_0$ when $|Z| > 1.96.$
If you 'invert the test' by solving for values $\lambda_0$
with $|X| \le 2,$ you get the interval $X + 2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{X + 1}$
of values of $\lambda_0.$

Suppose $X = 25.$ Then in R, a  simple 'grid search' gives the
interval $(16.8, 37.2):$

```
 lam = seq(0, 50, by=.001);  z = (25 - lam)/sqrt(lam)
 int = (abs(z) <= 2)
 min(lam[int]);  max(lam[int])
 ## 16.802
 ## 37.198
```

while the formula gives

```
 (25 + 2) + c(-2,2)*sqrt(25 + 1)
 ## 16.80196 37.19804
```

*Note:* The relatively simple form of the 'improved' 95%
confidence interval depends on conflating 1.96 and 2. For
other confidence levels, the algebra is very slightly messier.

Comment: Could you expand on the second question aswell?

Comment: When $\lambda$ is so small that 0 counts need to be considered, I worry about the validity of the normal approximation. One good journal article is by Barker in The American Statistician 2002 p85 (old enough to be on JSTOR at a univ. library). Nine different styles of Poisson CIs are discussed, some of which deal explicitly with 0 counts. (And there are philosophical difficulties with 0 counts unless you are in a Bayesian framework where you are sure $\lambda$ can be non-zero: Do you know the Higgs boson exists until you see the first one?)